# Why do I get border layout corruption when textField overflow to new page?

Tags: layout, jasper-reports, textfield

I am printing PDF report using Jasper Report. When data overflow and new page is being generated I get border layout corruption - a right border a bit bigger than left one (take a look at the picture).

Actually it's really weird behavior and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

[image]

my jrxml file:

```
<band height="70">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="c5529319-8868-4c4f-a68c-36f6ce79d652" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" markup="none">
                    <font size="15" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TEST DATA]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="bcea9da4-49d2-498a-aefc-40ebfb747183" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="216" y="50" width="339" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="91766db1-a506-4115-b31a-b8499ef306c9" positionType="Float" x="0" y="30" width="555" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Test Title]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement uuid="f2898317-cfda-4e91-b52b-95da97d80d49" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="50" width="216" height="20" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="none">
                    <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["First row"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="40">
            <elementGroup>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="232505af-9176-4cd3-ae46-18184e3dc468" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="216" y="0" width="339" height="40"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="13"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{second}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="a6e45bfc-9c09-4db8-8cc0-2fabfedf7653" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="216" height="40" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="none">
                        <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Second row"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </elementGroup>
        </band>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="1ae02b52-e3d7-4a4a-b805-e656f8734a49" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="216" y="0" width="339" height="40" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="232505af-9176-4cd3-ae46-18184e3dc468" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="216" y="0" width="339" height="40"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{third} == null) ? "" :
($F{third} ? "Yes" : "No")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="a6e45bfc-9c09-4db8-8cc0-2fabfedf7653" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="216" height="40" forecolor="#000000"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="none">
                    <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Third row Third row Third row Third row Third row Third row Third row Third row Third rowThird row Third row Third row Third row Third rowThird rowThird rowThird row Third row Third row "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="40">
            <elementGroup>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="232505af-9176-4cd3-ae46-18184e3dc468" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="216" y="0" width="339" height="40" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="13"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{fourth} == null) ? "" :
($F{fourth} ? "Yes" : "No")]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="a6e45bfc-9c09-4db8-8cc0-2fabfedf7653" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="216" height="40" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="none">
                        <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Fourth row Fourth row Fourth row Fourth row Fourth row Fourth row"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </elementGroup>
        </band>
        <band height="70">
            <elementGroup>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="93cd5464-2924-4403-8677-64558418afa1" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="216" height="40" forecolor="#000000"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="none">
                        <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Fiveth row Fiveth row Fiveth row Fiveth row Fiveth row Fiveth row"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="4bf32279-7361-4d05-b652-e37e7f4c96ba" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="216" y="0" width="339" height="40"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="13"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fiveth}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </elementGroup>
        </band>
```

Comment: Sometimes it helps to put a frame around the cells. Also, have you tried stretch type `Relative to band height`?

Answer (score 2):

I manage to [reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nshhU.png) your problem and as I see it is **a bug** (including fields in frame and/or setting `stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight"` did not solve the problem).

The **workaround** that I can see is to **remove** all **borders** from `textField` except right border on first field and include the fields in a **frame with border**.

```
<frame borderSplitType="DrawBorders">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="40" uuid="d2be3f0d-da65-4a09-b9c1-9d85c2f0af39">
    </reportElement>
    <box>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
    </box>
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="216" height="40" forecolor="#000000" uuid="a6e45bfc-9c09-4db8-8cc0-2fabfedf7653"/>
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
        </box>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="none">
            <font size="13" isBold="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Third row Third row Third row Third row Third row Third row Third row Third row Third rowThird row Third row Third row Third row Third rowThird rowThird rowThird row Third row Third row "]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="216" y="0" width="339" height="40" uuid="232505af-9176-4cd3-ae46-18184e3dc468"/>
        <textElement>
            <font size="13"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($P{third} == null) ? "" :($P{third} ? "Yes" : "No")]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
</frame>
```

The attribute `borderSplitType="DrawBorders"` on `frame` define whether to print or not print the bottom/top border of when split on new page

[image: Final solution]

Comment: OK. I will try it and respond later

Comment: It works, but I added an empty static text on whole band with borders and a small static text to left part with just right border. And I removed all borders from text fields. But unfortunately it doesn't work for HTML :(. In any cases - thank you. I can experiment in this way.

Comment: @Playmate Why do you not let the frame do the borders for you?, it is cleaner for other layouts.

Comment: Maybe. I've never used frames at all. Actually I have not a good feelings using Jasper Report. I've run into many layout bugs, they are not trivial. Maybe I am doing smth wrong. And this hook with borders looks suspiciously

Comment: @Playmate, I think it's more related to how you do your layout, maybe for example it would have been better to move all the stuff to next page when exporting to pdf.

Comment: In the case it's ok, but what about large text. I have the other elements with dynamic text and if I turn on Split Type to 'Prevent' it wont be a good idea.

Comment: Where did you find borderSplitType property? I don't see this property.

Comment: @Playmate sure I would need to know the whole report anyway I actually have had no direct problems except colspan in tables and dynamic columns, the  borderSplitType I found in the documentation : ), added it in jrxml (I need to check IDE, which one are you using?)

Comment: In JasperSoft Studio it is under properties >> advanced

Comment: I am using Intellij IDEA, but I am trying to add this property in iReport Designer 5.2.0

Comment: In iReport you need to added it directly to the jrxml (that attribute, ensures bottom border and top border when it splits to new page), you can also do without that way you understand that the record was split on page..

Comment: Thx, I will try it. Should this frame be inside a band element?

Comment: I tried. I can't use it. iReport doesn't see this property.

Comment: @Playmate but then you export do you not?, hence if you are using v6 lib in Intellj IDEA, added it in jrxml, export and if ok, consider to use JasperSoft Studio instead of old iReport.